# Bounds for $P(A\cap B)$ and $P(A\cup B)$

Tags: probability

> Let A and B be events where $P(A)=\frac13$ and $P(B)=\frac14$. Show bounds for $P(A\cup B)$ and $P(A\cap B)$.

I know that
\begin{align}
P(A\cup B) &= P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B) \\
P(A\cap B) &= P(A) P(B)
\end{align}
but I feel like I am answering the question wrong, confused as to what it even says. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: We're as confused as you are. You might want to paste it word for word, something tells me you've left some symbols (cardinality signs?) out.

Comment: @6005 question updated to show full question

Comment: The first equality holds for any events (it is the inclusion-exclusion principle). The second equality is the definition of independent events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of these probabilities ($P(A)$, $P(B)$, $P(A\cap B)$, and $P(A\cup B)$) are in the range $[0,1]$. So their theoretical minimum value is always $0$.

As you said, $$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$ So the maximum value of $P(A\cup B)$ is when $P(A\cap B)$ is minimum, i.e. zero. Note that this is when $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive. However, since none of the $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ can be negative, $P(A\cup B)$ cannot be less than the smallest between the two either. Hence,
$$0\le\min(P(A),P(B))\le \max(P(A),P(B)) \le P(A\cup B)\le \min(P(A)+P(B),1)\le1$$

Note that if $A\subset B$ then $0 \le P(A\cup B)=P(B)\le 1$

Regarding $P(A\cap B)$, since
$$P(A\cap B)= P(A)P(B|A)$$ you can imagine the following bounds
$$0\le P(A\cap B)\le \min(P(A),P(B))\le1$$

Comment: The last equation is false. Should be $P(A \cap B) \le \min(P(A), P(B))$.

Comment: oops, thanks for the typo

Comment: I suspect you can say $P(A\cup B)$ cannot be smaller than the ***larger*** of  the two, i.e. $\max(P(A),P(B)) \le P(A\cup B)$.  You cannot say  $P(A)+P(B)\le1$ as it depends on $A$ and $B$.  So your statement could be $0\le\max(P(A),P(B)) \le P(A\cup B)\le \min(P(A)+P(B), 1) \le 1$

Comment: $\max$ is not necessary since $A,B\subset S$ and since only $P(S)=1$, $P(A)+P(B)$ is never more than $1$

Comment: @msm No, you can have two events with probability 2/3, say. Also, in general there are proper subsets of the sample space which have probability 1. For example on $[0,1] $ with the Lebesgur measure the irrational in $[0,1] $ have this property.

Comment: Yes, we can imagine $A=S$ for instance.